# Rejected value [null] error even after assigning to the property

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm

I have a Grails Class called `MachineInstance` and the following code

```
machineInstanceInstance.reservationId = reservation.reservationId
println "-------"+reservation.reservationId+"====="+machineInstanceInstance.reservationId
```

I am specifically assigning `reservationId` to the object, it also gets printed but right below it I have following two lines of code. Both of these outputs error saying `Field error in object 'com.ch.MachineInstance' on field 'reservationId': rejected value [null]`

```
machineInstanceInstance.errors.each{println it}
if (machineInstanceInstance.hasErrors()) { more code   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using auto binding and after that inserting some data in the instance then you need to `validate` the instance.

Try this

```
machineInstanceInstance.validate()
machineInstanceInstance.errors.each{println it}
if (machineInstanceInstance.hasErrors()) { more code   }
```

Comment: Of course you can - start by reading the documentation, and also read and work through the examples in The Definitive Guide to Grails 2 or Grails in Action.

Comment: @BurtBeckwith is your comment a response to a question which has since been deleted?

Comment: Yep, it was something along the lines of "Thanks, I never would have come up with that myself"